# SQL Trigger not working as expected

Tags: sql, triggers

I have an SQL trigger as below

```
GO
create trigger ExpDateCheckCard
On Card 
FOR Insert, Update
As
Declare @expDate as DateTime
Select @expDate = inserted.ExpirationDate from inserted
if (YEAR(@expDate) < 1971 )
BEGIN
     UPdate Card set ExpirationDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' FROM Card, inserted
                                where inserted.RecordID = Card.RecordID
END
```

If i am right as per the trigger for every record inserted/updated when trigger runs it will check for the YEAR In the ExpirationDate column of that record and if the value is less than 1971 then it will update it with the date in the update query.

The weird thing is it is not working as expected.

The if condition does not seem to work.

Is anything wrong with this particular trigger.

Comment: You g eeting any error

Comment: No Error. The if condition always takes the expiration date of the first inserted or updated column and uses to check for rest of the records.

Comment: ExpirationDate  store date time or date .Year can take date argument and try with my code once

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like triggers are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES** - there's definitely something fundamentally wrong with the way you wrote this trigger.

SQL Server (assuming that's what you're using) will fire the trigger not once per row (as many folks including yourself) seem to think - the trigger is fired **once per batch** which might update or insert 10, 20, 50 rows at once.

Therefore, the `Inserted` pseudo table inside the trigger can (and **will!**) contain multiple rows - and in that case - what exactly does your statement here select?

```
Select @expDate = inserted.ExpirationDate from inserted
```

Either you'll just get one randon row (out of 50) and handle that (and ignore all 49 other rows), or you'll get an error....

You need to write your triggers with that in mind - you **MUST** always assume that `Inserted` (and `Deleted`) will contain multiple rows!

So you need to change your trigger to be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ExpDateCheckCard
ON dbo.Card 
FOR Insert, Update
AS
  UPDATE dbo.Card 
  SET ExpirationDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' 
  FROM dbo.Card c
  INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.RecordID = c.RecordID
  WHERE YEAR(i.ExpirationDate) < 1971
```

(*I've also changed your old-style JOIN syntax (comma-separated list of tables) to the ANSI standard that's been in place since 1992 - please **do not** use the comma-separated list of tables! Use **proper** ANSI JOINs*. See this blog post for more background info: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins))

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
create trigger ExpDateCheckCard
    On Card 
    FOR Insert, Update
    As
    BEGIN
    Declare @expDate as DateTime
    Select @expDate = inserted.ExpirationDate from inserted
    if (YEAR(@expDate) < 1971 ) Begin

         UPdate Card set ExpirationDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' FROM Card, inserted
                                    where inserted.RecordID = Card.RecordID
    end
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER ExpDateCheckCard AFTER INSERT,Update ON Card
   FOR EACH ROW

   Declare @expDate as DateTime
   Select @expDate = inserted.ExpirationDate from inserted
   if (YEAR(@expDate) < 1971 )
   BEGIN
      update Card 
      set ExpirationDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' FROM Card, inserted
      where inserted.RecordID = Card.RecordID
   END
```

Comment: This won't work - you're also assuming that `Inserted` only ever contains a single row - that's just not the case! What are you selecting here: `Select @expDate = inserted.ExpirationDate from inserted` if your trigger fires on an insert with 50 rows and `Inserted` contains 50 rows???